# What are the words for round eye and oriental eye shapes?

Tags: word-requests

I know the word for eyes but I can't find the words for round and oriental eye shapes. I am thinking touyoume and marume. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you're specifically looking for 熟語 but we would generally say 目が細い or 細い目 (the phrase 細目 also exists but that's more like "squint") for eastern eyes and 目が丸い or 丸い目 for western eyes (but this is also used for particularly round eastern eyes).

I think the issue is that even within the oriental eye type (at least here in Japan) there are multiple variations that each have their own name: どんぐり眼、ツリ目、タレ目、出目.

Additionally, people here don't necessarily see eye shape as the only deciding factor in whether an eye is "eastern" or "western". We also consider [一重]{ひとえ} and [二重]{ふたえ} and how 深い someone's [彫り]{ほり} (the space between the eyebrows and eyelids) is.